# The COM control can't display in a custom WPF window

Tags: wpf, com

Now I can use a COM control and display it in a WPF window.

I developed a custom WPF window for better UI.

When I put a COM control into the custom WPF window, sad event happened. The COM control didn't display and didn't throw a exception.

Could anybody give me a road to find the reason? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a COM object to a WPF application directly. While I haven't tried this myself, I believe that you would have more luck by adding a [`WindowsFormsHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control to your WPF application and then to add your COM object to that. Here's an example from the linked page:

```
<Window x:Class="HostingWfInWpf.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"  
    Title="HostingWfInWpf">    
    <Grid>    
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>    
    </Grid>     
</Window>
```

Clearly, you would need to replace the `mtbDate` control with your COM object, ensuring that you add the correct XAML Namespace Prefix for it.

Comment: thanks your answer. Yes, I had add my COM control in a WPF window. But if I replaced my custom window named BaseWindow instead of Window, it would not be display the com control.

Comment: You already said that *The COM control didn't display* in your question, so your comment doesn't make much sense to me.